# SQL QUERY PIVOT TABLE 2 INNER JOINS

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join, pivot-table

I have an excel pivot table connected to an old access .mdb file. I've successfully written a SQL query that contains an inner join. Now I require another table (STTRNH) from the db. I need to do another inner join to gain access to a field from the table. I've tried various ways but I've become stuck.

This is the query I've written, I think it is close:

```
SELECT STTRND.CDACCID, STTRND.CDDESC, STTRND.CDDOCNO, STTRND.CDTXNDATE, STTRND.CDTYPE, STTRND.CDSTATUS, STTRND.CDPRODID, BMASSD.BDCOMP, BMASSD.BDQTY, STTRND.CDQTYBAL
FROM STTRND
INNER JOIN BMASSD
ON STTRND.CDPRODID=BMASSD.BDASSID
INNER JOIN STTRNH 
ON STTRND.CDTRANNO=STTRNH.CHTRANNO;
```

How should I change my query so that it correctly returns the data that I need?

Comment: That looks correct, What field are you trying to access from STTRNH ? What error message are you getting when you run this?

Comment: Thank you for checking it Rachsherry. I'm trying to access STTRNH.CHDUEDATE, do I need to declare this in the opening SELECT statement? Sorry if this is blindingly obvious to do so.

Comment: yeah Just add it at the end of your select statement.

Comment: "Query did not run" & "Problems obtaining data". It's a fairly generic error with not a great amount of detail. I've seen it before when the query I wrote previously contained an error.

Comment: Ok will do and give it a shot. I'll let you know. Thank you

Comment: I've got the same error :-(

Comment: You are probably missing some parentheses. Try your query inside Access, or regenerate it in the Access Query Wizard - you'll see where Access puts additional parentheses.

Comment: That has worked a treat! I added the various tables and fields in to an Access query wizard then once it generated the new query right-clicked to show it as 'SQL view', I then copied the SQL query and fired it in to my excel pivot table. Job done!Should I show the correct parentheses way to mark it as solved? How do I give you some kudos for helping me? Thank so so much to all that helped.